# Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint in a composite key?

Tags: sql, sql-server, syntax-error

I am very new to SQL and am unable to understand this error: Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'UQ__Flight_L__5DD08D7924EB8625'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Flight_Leg'. The duplicate key value is (WN380)

```
Create Table Flight_Leg(
    Leg_number int not null,
    Departure_airport_code varchar(3),
    Scheduled_departure_time varchar(6),
    Arrival_airport_code varchar(3),
    Scheduled_arrival_time varchar(6),

    /*The maximum number of flight legs(Leg_number in the FLIGHT_LEG) cannot exceed 4*/
    CHECK (Leg_number<=4),

    Flight_number varchar(255) not null UNIQUE FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Flight(Flight_number),
    PRIMARY KEY (Leg_number,Flight_number),
);

INSERT INTO Flight_leg(Flight_number, Leg_number, Departure_airport_code, Scheduled_departure_time, Arrival_airport_code, Scheduled_arrival_time)
VALUES ('G4155', 1, 'SCK', '531PM', 'IWA', '814PM'),
    ('G4154', 1, 'IWA', '406PM', 'SCK', '451PM'),
    ('DL5841', 1, 'OAK', '1240PM', 'LAX', '200PM'),
    ('DL1149',1,'LAX','645PM', 'HNL', '1043PM'),
    ('HA48', 1, 'HNL', '215PM', 'OAK', '930PM'),
    ('AA1522', 1, 'SFO', '1159PM', 'ORD', '604AM'),
    ('AA3472', 1,'ORD', '719AM', 'MSN', '819AM'),
    ('WN380', 1,'MDW', '755AM', 'ONT', '1010AM'),
    ('WN380', 2, 'ONT', '1045AM', 'SMF', '1145AM'),
    ('B6624', 1, 'LAX', '915PM', 'JFK', '522AM');
```

In my head, I've made a composite key in flight_leg, so having duplicate values for WN380 should not produce this error?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: FYI, a `varchar(255)` is *not* an efficient column size for an index.  In data leaves a variable-length column will only take up the space that it needs, but in an index bucket it is another story.  You can't have a variable-width in a B-tree cell, so SQL Server maxes them out to make them all the same width.  Since your Flight_Numbers appear to be less than 10 characters long, you are wasting 245 characters in every index row.  This can also significantly affects the performance of the index as well.

Comment: @RBarryYoung thank you for the help!!! Are there any instances we should keep it at 255?

Comment: You should keep it at 255 if you have `Flight_Numbers` that can be 255 characters long.  When there's no specific restriction of a string-key field, I will usually set its length to 1.5-2.0 times the longest length that I have in my current data.  Note that for FK and JOIN reasons, you should keep its length the same in all tables that use it.

Comment: @RBarryYoung very grateful!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a uniqe constraint over Flight, which won't work

```
UNIQUE FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Flight(Flight_number)
```

So, you can't insert two identical Flight_Legs, no matter what your primary index is

Make a normal NON-UNIQUE KEY REFERENCE and it will work:

```
Flight_number varchar(255) not null FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Flight(Flight_number),
```

In your Flight Table, the Key can be UNIQE

best regards